# Requiring a module into a spec file for testing undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a module under

app/models/concerns/system_name.rb

this module looks like this and I need to test with the method

```
module SystemName
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def title_to_system_name(title)
    title.downcase.gsub(' ', '_').gsub(/[^0-9a-z\_]/i, '')
  end
end
```

Here is my spec file

```
require "spec_helper"
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/concerns/system_name.rb"

describe DataSource do 

  before(:each) do 
    @data_source = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:data_source)
  end 

  it "returns the system name in downcase format" do 
    expect(@data_source.system_name).to eq(title_to_system_name(@data_source.title))
  end 
end
```

I am getting this error when I run the spec file

```
Failures:

  1) DataSource returns the system name in downcase format
     Failure/Error: expect(@data_source.system_name).to eq(title_to_system_name(@data_source.title))
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `title_to_system_name' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::DataSource:0x0000010a97b908>
     # ./spec/models/data_source_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am sure I required the module correctly or am I doing it correctly in the first place?

updated I added SystemName

```
  it "returns the system name in downcase format" do 
    expect(@data_source.system_name).to eq(SystemName.title_to_system_name(@data_source.title))
  end
```

and here is my model

```
class DataSource < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SystemName

  #cut off a bunch of stuff
end
```

Comment: Try `SystemName.title_to_system_name`. Also you didn't show that you include that concern in you model.

Comment: @zishe just tried it, same error and the module is included in the model.

Comment: I think something in this question doesn't match reality. If you define your method as an instance method, you can't call it with `ModuleName.method_name`.